# Workbench did not install Mysql in services. Should I do it manually? How?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just installed mysql workbench CE 5.2.
I tried to create and open a connection 
and it said "Can't Connect to MYSQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)"

I looked around the answers on stackoverflow.
Eventually I found my way on services.
I saw that Mysql was not there.

dev.mysql.com says that I should install it with "mysqld" but it's not found inside the workbench installer.

What should I do?
If there is a way please tell it step by step.

Thank you!

Comment: chk if the mysql service is running, it could also be a port issue

Comment: Yup, I guessed he already installed it in the first place :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed MySql server on the local machine? Workbench is just a GUI program to make it easier to access a database - be it on you local machine or a remote machine.

Just install mysql on your local machine. See http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

There's a MySQL Installer for Windows which does install everything you need in this regard. Including several different server version, connectors, tools like Workbench and more. This installer should be your first attempt.

Of course you can also install the server separately. Download the msi and run the installer. Make sure you name your service properly. mysqld is usually not a name we use on Windows for a service. I recommend something like MySQL56 (for a 5.6 server).